# How can I build Debug and Release at once?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I select menu *Build* → *Build* or anything else, it only builds the currently selected configuration (Debug or Release). How can I make it build, for example, Release also when I'm in "Debug mode" (I have debug selected)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with "Batch Build", although it's not available in the Express version.

Anyway, you don't want to be building from the GUI anyway. You should be using MSBuild or something of that nature to automate your build process.

Comment: Why not nAnt? Sounds good to me. Everything that automates build is better than manual build.

Comment: Batch Build is available in Visual Studio 2008/2010 Pro. It is not available in VC# Express.

Comment: “You should not be building from the GUI” is an extremely lame excuse to have no proper function to invoke all compile-time checks for all configurations. This way it is possible (without noticing) to make a change to the code which works fine in Debug mode, but fails to compile only in Release mode.

Comment: @Timwi There is a function to do it, "Batch Build". But building for release should be automated.

Comment: There's obviously no problem with using NAnt. It's just that Visual Studio project files are *already* valid MSBuild project files; there's no *need* to use NAnt.

Comment: @Jaroslav It seems [it is indeed available in the express version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13586828/501196).

Answer (score 5):

In the Visual Studio GUI, go to the menu

*Build* → *Batch Build*

This will pop up a window with all the possible combinations of projects and their configurations. Select all the items you want to build together and click the <kbd>Build</kbd> button on the right side of the window.

That's it.

There is also a button to rebuild a group of configurations instead of build (which is an incremental build).

There is also an option to select/deselect all configurations/projects to build/rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the build button and not build it via menus, you can use the **Post-build Command** function (or pre-build - it is up to you).

You can parametrize the commands using project properties via macros. It can be useful for auto-copying of final assemblies to central location, etc.

Answer (score -6):

In order to build for Release mode, the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, but I don't think you can build both at the same time...

I don't understand why you would need to.

Comment: When I'm done with debugging I want to build Release version, because I think its faster than the Debug version. That does not mean that I'm done in Debug Version and I might still want to add some features.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. You want to build the Release **right after** the Debug is finished building?

Comment: No, I want some special way to create the Release version when I think the app is ready to be released.

Comment: You can publish the project by right clicking the 'Properties' item under your project, and then clicking 'Open' and click the 'Publish' tab.

But if you just want to create a release version, then Ctrl+F5 is the way to do it.

Comment: Firstly, CTRL+F5 will build using the **current build configuration**, just without actually attaching to the process.
Secondly, building using the **Run** command won't build Library projects.

Comment: Wrong answer. Ctrl+F5 builds the same thing as F5.

Comment: @IAdapter, I don't quite understand your comment. What's wrong with building Debug version each time you want to debug and switching to Release configuration when you want to test release version or deploy it? I just can't see any point in building both configurations at the same time if you don't plan to run them simultaneously.

Comment: isn't ctrl+f5 does a Full compile & run?